# Problem related to the cloud firestore database connection when I use some browsers

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firefox, google-cloud-firestore

Hy, 
I'm creating a web app with Vue.js.The app is basically a multi user real time quiz, in which every user have to choose a role and to answer questions related with his role. I use a collection in cloud firestore database to store questions associated to each role and answers associated to each question. My problem is related to the fact that the app doesn't load informations from the cloud firestore database, like question's text or answer's text, when I use some browsers. I don't have problems with browsers like Chrome, Safari or old version of Firefox (question and answer are loaded correctly). I have this problem when I use the latest version of Firefox and Microsoft Edge. The errors that I get in this case is:

[image]

I need to understand the nature of this error and the way to fix this problem. Hope that you can help me.

These are the queries that I use to acquire informations:

```
db
  .collection("Utenti")
  .doc(this.userId)
  .collection("Domande")
  .doc(this.questionId)
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    this.questionValue = doc.get("Testo");
  }),
  db
    .collection("Utenti")
    .doc(this.userId)
    .collection("Domande")
    .doc(this.questionId)
    .collection("Risposte")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = doc;

        this.answers.push(data);
      });
    });
```

Where db is the database reference imported from the firebase configuration file and "this.userId" and "this.questionId" are initialized variables.

This is the content of the firebase configuration file:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'


const app = Firebase.initializeApp({

apiKey: "*****",
authDomain: "******",
databaseURL: "********",
projectId: "****",
storageBucket: "*****",
messagingSenderId: "****",
appId: "*****",
measurementId: "***"



}) 

export const db = app.firestore()
```

Comment: As much as possible, don't use images of text on Stack Overflow.  Copy the text into the question itself so that it's easy to read, copy, and search for.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate error messages here.

The first one is suggesting that you have a poor internet connection to Firesetore.

The second one is saying you're passing an invalid value to `doc()`. You will need to debug your code to figure out why either `this.userId` or `this.questionId` are undefined.